# Run multiple bat files in one bat file server 2012

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-server-2012

I have a simple app that I need to run on my servers. I need to run it independently on each drive of the server. I have a simple bat file that runs great on server 2008, but just flys through it on 2012 without actually doing anything. Is there a syntax difference going into 2012?
I run as Administrator

This is the simple batch file. Again it works great on 2003 and 2008. But it just runs through and exits without errors on 2012.

```
call C:\SCAN\ScanningSingledrive_v2.bat C:
call C:\SCAN\ScanningSingledrive_v2.bat D:
call C:\SCAN\ScanningSingledrive_v2.bat E:
call C:\SCAN\ScanningSingledrive_v2.bat F:
```

Comment: Perhaps if you were to list `ScanningSingledrive_v2.bat` it might elicit meaningful responses. As it stands, your posted batch appears to have no problems.